# Некорректность адаптивности сайта

Tags: css, wordpress, вёрстка

Всем добрый день!

Сегодня полдня голову ломал, форумы курил, но ничего не помогло...
Суть проблемы: при загрузке сайта на мобильных устройствах, с правой стороны есть серая полоса, которая уходит только когда скроллишь сайт до середины. Если смотреть в инспекторе кода - то она всегда на виду, пока не пролистаешь до середины, потом уходит.
Если открывать на телефоне - то в большинстве своем серая полоса есть, если двинуть экран пальцем влево. И тоже она пропадает лишь при прокрутке до середины.
Эта проблема присутствует только на главной странице.
Сам решить так и не смог...падинги у всех элементов главной страницы проверил, поправил.
Метатег в хэдэре присутствует.

Сам сайт: https://compus-help.ru/

---

[image: скрин]

Comment: Вы зря волнуетесь - у Вас все нормально :)
Черная полоса справа видна если выбрать телефон Pixel 2 в chrome.
НО! Сверху написано что у pixel2 разрешение 411*731
У Вас первый тег header - а у него width 411.2px
Это значит что все нормально . - посмотрел сайт с телефона - а он нормально показывает

Comment: Кажется, это как-то связано со слайдером

Comment: По правде, есть одно решение: отключайте лишний функционал, и смотрите что даёт эти отступы. Также вы можете сами написать слайдер, это не так сложно.

Comment: из-за translateX, добавьте `overflow-x: hidden` для секций